# Merging dataframes in pandas while ignoring NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
df_a
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  1.0

df_b
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

How would I go about merging/concatenating them so the result dataframe looks like this:

```
df_c
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  1.0
```

The way I got closer conceptually was by using `pd.merge(df_a, df_b, "right")`, but all values on `df_a` ended up replaced.

Is there any way to ignore `NaN` values when merging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case do `combine_first`

```
df_c = df_b.combine_first(df_a)
df_c
Out[151]: 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_c = df_a.combine_first(df_b)
df_c
A   B   C
0   1.0 NaN 2.0
1   NaN 1.0 NaN
2   2.0 NaN 1.0

df_d = df_b.combine_first(df_a)
df_d
A   B   C
0   1.0 NaN 2.0
1   NaN 2.0 NaN
2   2.0 NaN 1.0
```